# A C++ factory pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory-pattern

#### Guitar class

```
 class Guitar {

private: std::string _name;

protected: mutable std::auto_ptr< HeadStock > _HeadStock;
protected: mutable std::auto_ptr< NeckStrap > _NeckStrap;
protected: mutable std::vector< Bridge* > _Bridge;
protected: mutable std::auto_ptr< Strings > _Strings;
protected: mutable std::auto_ptr< Switches > _Switches;
protected: mutable std::auto_ptr< GuitarBody > _GuitarBody;

public: virtual void prepare() const = 0;

private: Guitar( const Guitar& ); // Disable copy constructor
     private: void operator=( const Guitar& ); // Disable assignment operator

protected: Guitar() {
}
public: virtual ~Guitar() 
     {
     for( std::vector< Bridge* >::iterator iterator = _Bridge.begin();
     _Bridge.end() != iterator; ++iterator ) {delete *iterator;
}
_Bridge.clear();

}
public: virtual void bake() const {
    std::cout << "Bake for 25 minutes at 350" << std::endl;
}
public: virtual void cut() const {
    std::cout << "Cutting the pizza into diagonal slices" << std::endl;
}
public: virtual void box() const {
    std::cout << "Place pizza in official PizzaStore box" << std::endl;
}
public: void setName( std::string name) {
    _name = name;
}
public: std::string getName() const {
    return _name;
}
public: std::string toString() const {
    std::stringstream value; 
    value << "---- " << _name.c_str() << " ----" << std::endl;

    if( _HeadStock.get() != 0 ) {
        value << _HeadStock->toString();
        value << std::endl;
    }
    if( _NeckStrap.get() != 0 ) {
        value << _NeckStrap->toString();
        value << std::endl;
    }
    if( _Strings.get() != 0 ) {
        value << _Strings->toString();
        value << std::endl;
    }
    if( _GuitarBody.get() != 0 ) {
        value << _GuitarBody->toString();
        value << std::endl;
    }

    if( _Switches.get() != 0 ) {
        value << _Switches->toString();
        value << std::endl;
    }

         if( _Bridge.size() != 0 ) 
              {
              for( std::vector< Bridge* >::iterator iterator = _Bridge.begin 
              ();_Bridge.end() != iterator; ++iterator ) 
              {
    value << ( *iterator )->toString() << ", ";
    }
    value << std::endl;
    }

    return value.str();
}
   };
```

#### GuitarStore class

```
   class GuitarStore {

protected: GuitarStore() {
}
public: virtual ~GuitarStore() = 0 {
}
public: std::auto_ptr< Guitar > orderGuitar( std::string type ) const {
    std::auto_ptr< Guitar > guitar( createGuitar( type ) );
    std::cout << "--- Making a " << guitar->getName() << " ---" << std::endl;
    guitar->prepare();
    guitar->bake();
    guitar->cut();
    guitar->box();
    return guitar;
}
    public: virtual std::auto_ptr< Guitar > createGuitar( std::string type ) const = 0;
 };
```

#### GuitarComponentFactory class

```
 class GuitarComponentFactory {
public: virtual HeadStock* createHeadStock() const = 0;
public: virtual NeckStrap* createNeckStrap() const = 0;
public: virtual Strings* createStrings() const = 0;
public: virtual std::vector< Bridge* > createBridge() const = 0;
public: virtual Switches* createSwitches() const = 0;
public: virtual GuitarBody* createGuitarBody() const = 0;
public: virtual ~GuitarComponentFactory() = 0 {
}};
```

////////// CLASS ELECTRIC GUITAR  ///////////////

```
   class ElectricGuitar : public Guitar {

private: mutable std::auto_ptr< GuitarComponentFactory > _ingredientFactory;

public: explicit ElectricGuitar( GuitarComponentFactory* ingredientFactory ) :
    _ingredientFactory( ingredientFactory ) { assert( ingredientFactory );
}
public: void prepare() const {
     std::cout << "Preparing " << getName().c_str() << std::endl;
_HeadStock = std::auto_ptr< HeadStock>( _ingredientFactory->createHeadStock() );
_NeckStrap = std::auto_ptr< NeckStrap>( _ingredientFactory->createNeckStrap() );
_Strings = std::auto_ptr< Strings>( _ingredientFactory->createStrings() );
_Switches= std::auto_ptr< Switches>( _ingredientFactory->createSwitches() );
    if( _Bridge.empty() ) 
        _Bridge = _ingredientFactory->createBridge();
}
  };
```

#### ElectricGuitarComponentFactory class

```
 class ElectricGuitarComponentFactory : public GuitarComponentFactory {

public: HeadStock* createHeadStock() const {
    return new AngledHeadStock();
}
public: NeckStrap* createNeckStrap() const {
    return new LeatherNeckStrap();
}
public: Strings* createStrings() const {
    return new NylonStrings();
}
public: std::vector< Bridge* > createBridge() const {
    std::vector< Bridge* > bridge;
    bridge.push_back( new ChromeBridge() );
    return bridge;
}

public: Switches* createSwithes() const {
    return new SPDT_Switches();
}

public: GuitarBody* createGuitarBody() const {
    return new HollowGuitarBody();
}

  };
```

#### ElectricGuitarStore class

```
  class ElectricGuitarStore : public GuitarStore 
  {

public: std::auto_ptr< Guitar > createGuitar( std::string item ) const{

std::auto_ptr< Guitar > guitar( 0 );

GuitarComponentFactory* ingredientFactory = new ElectricGuitarComponentFactory();

if( item.compare( "Electric" ) == 0 ) {
guitar = std::auto_ptr< Guitar >( new ElectricGuitar( ingredientFactory ) );
        guitar->setName( "Electric GuitarBody" );


return guitar;

}

 };
```

I get the following error:

```
1>c:\users\brian\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cst276lab_3\project3_main.cpp(37): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'c:\users\brian\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cst276lab_3\guitar.hpp(365)' was matched
```

---

**Edit**: I'm sorry; this is the error I get:

```
1>c:\users\brian\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cst276lab_3\guitar.hpp(456): error C2259: 'ElectricGuitarComponentFactory' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

---

**Edit**: I have narrowed the error down to this line:

```
GuitarComponentFactory* ingredientFactory = new ElectricGuitarComponentFactory();
```

<sub>Sorry about the unindented code; I'm new at this</sub>

Comment: I'm somewhat amused by the concept of a guitar which is baked, cut diagonally, and placed into pizza boxes...

Comment: That's the biggest wall of code I've seen. You aren't likely to get too many people wading through that epic saga to help you.

Comment: Oh look, unindented wall of code. How could anyone miss a brace in there.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as too localized. Try doing a little more work yourself, instead of giving us a huge block of code and a syntax error and expected to somehow figure it out. For starters, I recommend you isolate the error down to a few lines of code.

Comment: @Earlz - "I recommend you isolate the error down to a few lines of code" If you pay attention to the post you will see he narrowed it down to ONE line of code..

Comment: @iceland That was 7 minutes later, in the second **Edit** block

Answer (score 2):

```
public: Switches* createSwithes() const {
return new SPDT_Switches();
```

Has a typo: Swithes should be Switches:

```
public: Switches* createSwitches() const {
    return new SPDT_Switches();
```

This is the cause of the error, as the createSwitches() method was seen as not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to set this to zero

```
std::auto_ptr< Guitar > guitar( 0 );
```

Rather,

```
std::auto_ptr< Guitar > guitar;
```